# communicating with a functional component outside of react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to be able to communicate with my react component from outside of the component in normal HTML (needed due to embedding a component in another system).

I've been researching this and I have seen advice that you can add component to `window` by adding a ref on the rendered element like so:

```
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello
      ref={(element) => {
        window.helloComponent = element;
      }}
    />,
    rootElement
  );
```

But for me it doesn't work and generates this warning:

> index.js:27 Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

The component doesn't get added to window object so the reference does not work from the html button outside of react component.

I've been trying various ways with createRef() to add to window but can't figure it out.  I am unable to relate the forwardRef() docs to my current situation.

Here is my code:

```js
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

if (rootElement) {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello
      ref={(element) => {
        window.helloComponent = element;
      }}
    />,
    rootElement
  );
}

function Hello() {
  function alertOne() {
    alert("hi from 1");
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, world! </h1> <UpdateButton />
    </div>
  );
}

function UpdateButton() {
  function alertTwo() {
    alert("hi from 2");
  }

  return <button onClick={alertTwo}> Click Me Inside React</button>;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <button onclick="window.helloComponent.alertOne()">
      Click me outside react
    </button>
    <div id="root"></div>
```

I would like to know the right technique for accessing `alertOne()` and `alertTwo()` from outside of any react component, just from html on same page the component renders.

Comment: One issue is the typo in your button: `helloConponent`.

Comment: Thanks updated.  Unfortunately not the main issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Saving the function in the window object:

```js
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

if (rootElement) {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello />,
    rootElement
  );
}

function Hello() {

  function alertOne() {
    alert("hi from 1");
  }
  
  window.helloComponentAlert = alertOne;
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, world! </h1> <UpdateButton />
    </div>
  );
}

function UpdateButton() {
  function alertTwo() {
    alert("hi from 2");
  }

  return <button onClick={alertTwo}> Click Me Inside React</button>;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script>
const handleClick = () => {
  window.helloComponentAlert();
}
</script>

<button onclick="handleClick()">Click me outside react</button>
<div id="root"></div>
```

---

### Event driven approach:

```js
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

if (rootElement) {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello/>,
    rootElement
  );
}

function Hello() {

  function alertOne() {
    alert("hi from 1");
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
     window.addEventListener(
       "someEvent",
       alertOne,
       false
    );
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, world! </h1> <UpdateButton />
    </div>
  );
}

function UpdateButton() {
  function alertTwo() {
    alert("hi from 2");
  }

  return <button onClick={alertTwo}> Click Me Inside React</button>;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script>
const handleClick = () => {
  var someEvent = new Event("someEvent");
  window.dispatchEvent(someEvent);
}
</script>

<button onclick="handleClick()">Click me outside react</button>
<div id="root"></div>
```

---

### Event driven approach with passing additional data:

```js
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

if (rootElement) {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello/>,
    rootElement
  );
}

function Hello() {

  function alertOne(e) {
    alert("hi from 1 " + e.detail);
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
     window.addEventListener(
       "someEvent",
       alertOne,
       false
    );
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, world! </h1> <UpdateButton />
    </div>
  );
}

function UpdateButton() {
  function alertTwo() {
    alert("hi from 2");
  }

  return <button onClick={alertTwo}> Click Me Inside React</button>;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script>
const handleClick = () => {
  var someEvent = new CustomEvent("someEvent", {detail: "SomeAdditionalData"});
  window.dispatchEvent(someEvent);
}
</script>

<button onclick="handleClick()">Click me outside react</button>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
window.alertEvent = new Event('alert');

if (rootElement) {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello/>,
    rootElement
  );
}

function Hello() {
  function alertOne() {
    alert("hi from 1");
  }
  window.addEventListener('alert',alertOne);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, world! </h1> <UpdateButton />
    </div>
  );
}

function UpdateButton() {
  function alertTwo() {
    alert("hi from 2");
  }

  return <button onClick={alertTwo}> Click Me Inside React</button>;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <button onclick="window.dispatchEvent(window.alertEvent)">
      Click me outside react
    </button>
    <div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that I have created where you could pass some values as well using the event publish subscribe pattern in javascript.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-r7dfn?file=/index.js