# Re-render the react component based on onclick event assoicated with button created as part of innerHTML in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Primary Objective: Re-render the react component based on onclick event assoicated with button created as part of innerHTML in vanilla javascript.

Additional Details: An AJAX request is made after the onclick event.This request can be made either in vanilla javascript or from the react component. Based on the fetched results, the react component has to re-render itself.

What is already tried?:

1. Just importing the results into react component file. As expected, the results are not updating as per the event.
2. Accessing the react method from vanilla javascript. Please check the details below.

myReactComponent code:

```
const myReactComponent = () =>
{
 const [attribute,setAttribute] = useState([]);

 const assignValueToAttribute = function assignValue(results){
 attribute = results;
 setAttribute(attribute);
}

}

export default myReactComponent;
```

myjavascript code:

```
import myReactComponent from './React/components/myReactComponent'

let getResults=[];
let getResultsUrl="https://myresultspath.com";

function updateResults(){

 $.ajax({
 url: getResultsUrl,
 type: "get",
 contentType: "application/json",
  success: function (data) {
  getResults.push(data);

  },
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
 console.log(textStatus);
},
  myReactComponent.assignValueToAttribute(getResults);

}
```

Error message:

> assignValueToAttribute is not a function.

The above solution is based on one of the four methods suggested here:http://www.primaryobjects.com/2017/05/08/integrating-react-with-an-existing-jquery-web-application/

I have chosen the above method since it involved less code refactoring. If the above approach is correct in principle, please let me know where did I commit mistake. Otherwise, kindly suggest the right approach to achieve the primary objective based on the details provided. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
const myReactComponent = (results) =>
{
 const [attribute,setAttribute] = useState([]);

 const assignValueToAttribute = function assignValue(results){
 attribute = results;
 setAttribute(attribute);
}

}

export default myReactComponent;
```

myjavascript code:

```
import myReactComponent from './React/components/myReactComponent'

let getResults=[];
let getResultsUrl="https://myresultspath.com";

function updateResults(){

 $.ajax({
 url: getResultsUrl,
 type: "get",
 contentType: "application/json",
  success: function (data) {
  getResults.push(data);

  },
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
 console.log(textStatus);
},
  myReactComponent.assignValueToAttribute(getResults);

}
```

Comment: ...Thanks for looking into the issue. The error message persists.

Comment: If you are interested in the solution, please check the procedure I followed to resolve the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I could achieve my primary objective by using the "Event Driven method" suggested at
[communicating with a functional component outside of react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63698105/communicating-with-a-functional-component-outside-of-react)

Steps I followed:
1.Dispatched global Custom event after I fetched details from the backend through AJAX request as shown below.

```
function updateResults(){
  let getResults;
  var someEvent = new Event("someEvent")

 $.ajax({
 url: getResultsUrl,
 type: "get",
 contentType: "application/json",
  success: function (data) {
  getResults = data;
  window.dispatchEvent(someEvent)

  },
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
 console.log(textStatus);
},
  

}
```

2. Insdide the react component file

   ```
    React.useEffect(() => {
     window.addEventListener(
       "someEvent",
       "functionToBeCalled"
       ,
       false
    );
   ```

   }, []);
3. You can get the fetched details from ajax request in either of the two ways.
   i. Importing the fetched details from the vanilla js file into react component file
   (OR)
   ii.Making it part of the event dispatch

   ```
    var someEvent = new CustomEvent("someEvent", {detail: "SomeAdditionalData"});
   ```

if you need more clarity on second approach please refer the above link.

4. Assign the data to the state variable using "setState" of "useState" hook in the function to be called.

   ```
    import fetchedData from "vanillaFile.js"

    [variableToBeChanged, setVariableToBeChanged] = useState(); //initially inside the component

    functionTobeCalled()
    {
    setVariableToBeChanged(fetchedData);
    }
   ```

I am thankful to the members @95faf8e76605e973 and @Guerilla